# PHPMailer - How to add attachment of a pdf file from POST

Tags: php, phpmailer, radix

I send a PDF file from my Android device to the PHP Server, then send it via PHPMailer.
The sent PDF is encoded Base64 : `Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);`

I receive the data by this way: `$pdf= $_POST["pdf"];`

Then i send it with PHPMailer : `$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, 'ock.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf')`

The mail did not send when i add "AddStringAttachment", but when i remove it, i receive the mail.

Ps: I already try : `$mail->addAttachment($pdf, 'ock.pdf')` & `$mail->addAttachment(base64_decode($pdf), 'ock.pdf')`

Comment: Where is your link between the variable `$pdf` and your varaible `$image`?

Comment: @FabianN. i correct it, it was a mistake.

Comment: Have you tried to look into that variable, to be sure, that its not empty or something like this? Maybe you send the file via `multipart/form-data`? Then the data is stored inside `$_FILES['pdf']` as a path to a temporary file on the server. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: You're sounding very confused - just look at [the `send_file_upload` example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer.